# Cannot sign in to google in QWebEngineView: This app may not be secure

Tags: c++, qt, qwebengineview

I'm a beginner to QT and I recently developed a simple desktop browser using QWebEngineView to view the google search page. Everything works fine but when I enter my email to sign in to my google account, it Says,

Couldn't sign you in.
This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.

How to fix this?

Here are the codes just in case.

```
mainwindow.h

'''
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWebEngineView>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

'''

mainwindow.cpp

'''

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QWebEngineView* google = new QWebEngineView(this);
    google->setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com/"));
    google->show();
    setCentralWidget(google);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

'''

main.cpp

'''

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.setGeometry(100, 110, 800, 600);
    w.setWindowTitle("IBrowse");
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/new/prefix1/Screenshot_2020-04-29 Step 4 of 4 Save Logo LogoMaker.png"));
    w.showMaximized();
    return a.exec();
}
```

'''

**Thanks!**

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: windows 10 64bit, Qt version = 5.14.2, compiler = MSVC 2017

Comment: Do you get any warning on the console?

Comment: no warnings in console

Comment: Did you manage to figure out a solution to this problem @Dev-I-J

Comment: Not Yet. I am trying to. sigh

Comment: https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/issues/5182

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a potential workaround mentioned in this GitHub issue:

https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/issues/5182

Comment: Thank You So Much @harshithdwivedi! Accepted your answer.